# Reading from Distinct Ranges into Array and Overwriting to Same Ranges in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, distinct, cells

I would like to read from distinct ranges, in which there are values calculated through some formula in those cells, in VBA and overwrite these ranges with the values that have been saved in order to automatically get rid of the formulae in the cells.

The code looks as follows:

```
allValues = Range("AR8:AW8,AR10:AW10,AR12:AW24,AR26:AW52,AR54:AW61,AR64:AW87,AR89:AW94,AR96:AW96,AR98:AW104,AR106:AW106,AR108:AW110,AR112:AW122,AR125:AW140,AR142:AW162,AR164:AW192,AR194:AW196,AR198:AW198,AR200:AW202,AR204:AW218,AR220:AW230,AR232:AW232,AR234:AW240").Value

Range("AR8:AW8,AR10:AW10,AR12:AW24,AR26:AW52,AR54:AW61,AR64:AW87,AR89:AW94,AR96:AW96,AR98:AW104,AR106:AW106,AR108:AW110,AR112:AW122,AR125:AW140,AR142:AW162,AR164:AW192,AR194:AW196,AR198:AW198,AR200:AW202,AR204:AW218,AR220:AW230,AR232:AW232,AR234:AW240")= allValues
```

For conjunctive ranges such an idea worked out but for these not at all.

I appreciate any input.

Comment: Do you need to store the values in memory or are you simply trying to convert from formulas to values?

Comment: I am simply trying to replace the formulas by the corresponding values without using a for loop. I need not store them in memory. Thanks for letting me clear that up!

Comment: You will run into a lot of problems dealing with multiple selections. I do not believe you can avoid a for loop in this case unless you select a contiguous range. Have you considered changing the formulas to values for the whole worksheet? Or is there a particular reason you're averse to using a for loop?

Comment: thank you Nathan for your input, in the end I decided for for loop :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a multi-area range, iterate on the areas:

```
Dim r As Range
For Each r In Sheet1.Range("AR8:AW8, AR10:AW10, ..., ...").Areas
    r.Value = r.Value
Next
```

Comment: Nice answer. Much better than what I had!

Comment: tailored to the needs, simply brilliant. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go like follows:

```
With Range("AR8:AW8,AR10:AW10,AR12:AW24,AR26:AW52,AR54:AW61,AR64:AW87,AR89:AW94,AR96:AW96,AR98:AW104,AR106:AW106,AR108:AW110,AR112:AW122,AR125:AW140,AR142:AW162,AR164:AW192,AR194:AW196,AR198:AW198,AR200:AW202,AR204:AW218,AR220:AW230,AR232:AW232,AR234:AW240")
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: I tested this method and found that it only retained the first value - not all the independent values. Do you get the same?

Comment: I appreciate your input